# Which is the best technique that can be used for pdf compression in MVC4 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I need to implement PDF compression so that it can be easily downloaded in MVC4 application.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple for compressing file in MVC.

> PDF document has been widely used by large enterprises and organizations to distribute and view documents. But in practical applications, the large size issue of PDF document (especially when the PDF document contains large number of images) causes a heavy burden on the bandwidth costs, network transmission time and digital storage. Thus, how to compress large-size existing PDF documents is quite useful for increasing the efficiency and productiveness of existing document management system.

[Here is how to compress file.](http://www.rasteredge.com/how-to/csharp-imaging/pdf-compressing/)

Comment: @Deepak If this helped your question mark this as correct answer and vote up so other people have this same problem can find the answer.